# Creating a hello world application with socket.io

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, cygwin

When I run on the client the Hello World is printed but what console log I have written that does not shown event on client and server both. Why?

Client code:

```
<script src="C:\cygwin\usr\local\lib\node\.npm\socket.io\0.6.10\package\support\socket.io-client\socket.io.js"></script> 
<script> 
 var socket = new io.Socket('http://localhost:8080/'); 
 socket.connect();
 socket.on('connect', function(){
    console.log("on connect");

 }) ;
 socket.on('message', function(){ 
    console.log("on message");

 }) ;
 socket.on('disconnect', function(){ 
    console.log("on disconn");
 }) ;
</script>
```

Server code:

```
var http = require('http'),  
    io = require('socket.io'), // for npm, otherwise use require('./path/to/socket.io') 

server = http.createServer(function(req, res){ 
 // your normal server code 
 res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'}); 
 res.end('<h1>Hello world</h1>'); 
});
server.listen(8080);

// socket.io 
var socket = io.listen(server); 
socket.on('connection', function(client){ 
  // new client is here! 
  client.on('message', function(){ 
    console.log("on message");
  }) 
  client.on('disconnect', function(){
    console.log("on disconnect");
  }) 
});
```

Comment: What log messages are you expecting in this case? Simple connecting will only output "on connect" on the client. If you are running Firefox, make sure Firebug is running or you won't see the log.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
var socket = new io.Socket('localhost:8080');
```

instead of

```
var socket = new io.Socket('http://localhost:8080/');
```

Answer (score 0):

It's probably because of browser same origin security restriction - socket.io client library doesn't come from the server you connect to.

I don't know about rather ancient 0.6.9, but newer versions of `socket.io` serve socket.io client automatically, so you should use `/socket/socket.io.js` instead of `file://` URL you currently use. Check the documentation for exact URL.